# Can you load an img tag's src inside javascript file and then draw it to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

index.html

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <title>DCView</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dcview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:center; text-align:center;">
        <canvas id="dcviewCanvas" width="1024" height="1024"/>
        <img id="bgImage" src="" hidden="true"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dcview.js

```
var backgroundImage,
    backgroundImageSrc,
    canvas,
    context;

window.onload = function()
{
    //Initially set the background image source to DCView.png
    backgroundImageSrc = "Foundation\\WebService\\Downloads\\DCView.png";

    //Load the background image with the given source
    loadBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSrc);
}

function loadBackgroundImage(imageSrc)
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("dcviewCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    backgroundImage = document.getElementById("bgImage");
    backgroundImage.src = imageSrc;

    context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
}
```

When I try to load index.html in chrome it doesn't load the background image. But when I hard-code the src of the img tag in to that path, it proceeds to load it in.

The only error chrome gives me is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

It points this error to line 47 in dcview.js.

Is the way I am going about this completely wrong? I am a beginner with HTML and Javascript.

Thanks,

Virat

**UPDATED**

dcview.js

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //Initially set the background image source to DCView.png
    backgroundImageSrc = 'Foundation/WebService/Downloads/Layout_Basement.png';

    //Load the background image which is initially set to DCView.png
    loadBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSrc);

    //Load the other various pin images;
    loadPinImages();
}

function loadBackgroundImage(imageSrc)
{
    context = document.getElementById('dcviewCanvas').getContext('2d');

    backgroundImage = new Image();
    backgroundImage.src = imageSrc;

    backgroundImage.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    };
}
```

**UPDATED**

Once I have loaded the background image, other images I draw on top are being drawn underneath the background image. Ideas?

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //Initially set the background image source to DCView.png
    backgroundImageSrc = 'Foundation/WebService/Downloads/Layout_Basement.png';

    //Load the background image which is initially set to DCView.png
    loadBackgroundImage(backgroundImageSrc);

    canvas = document.getElementById('dcviewCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(sortationLanePinBlue, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I did not count, but it does not look like you have shown us 47 lines of code here.

Comment: You are correct, I removed some code when posting this question compared to the original.
Basically it is pointing to the line: "window.onload = function()"
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problems but it seems you are assigning the value of the .src property to backgroundImage and then trying to access the .src property on the next line. That doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: I found the error causing the Unexpected SyntaxError and fixed it (see the edit I made to the question). But now nothing is being displayed in the canvas the first time I load my screen; if I refresh it I can then view my image.

Comment: Yes you are correct @bmceldowney, I didn't see your comment because I was typing mine out in the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Javascript Image class to draw to a canvas. [See this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images).